# fastest stride 2 gather

Tags: x86-64, sse, avx, avx2

I know there has been a question with fast stride-3 gather with AVX2. I am wondering what is the fastest stride 2 gather sequence, say I want to load all odd elements of a length 16 vector into `ymm0`.

In particular, I am wondering about the relative benefits and costs of

1. using the AVX2 gather with stride 2 and
2. issuing two vector loads and then using a sequence of blend and shuffle instructions.

If 2) is always better than 1), what is the best sequence of instructions to use?

Comment: Could you clarify what the size of the elements is?

Comment: The best solution will depend on port-usage of the surrounding code (also on whether you need the even elements as well), but a gather will quite unlikely be the most efficient way.

Comment: For element sizes of 32-bit or 64-bit, 256-bit loads + `vshufps` + (`vpermd` or `vpermq`) is likely best.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the relative order of elements? Or it fine if the elements appear in some other, but predictable, order?

Comment: The size is 32 bit float. I need to preserve the relative order of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vshufps` and `vpermps` both execute on port 5 (intel Skylake), I would prefer `vblendps`+`vpermps` over `vshufps`+`vpermps`, for a better instruction mix. On intel skylake `vblendps` can execute on port 0, 1 or 5. The following solution uses 2 overlapping vector loads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256 stide_2_load_odd(float * a){
    __m256 x_lo = _mm256_loadu_ps(&a[1]);
    __m256 x_hi = _mm256_loadu_ps(&a[8]);
    __m256 x_b = _mm256_blend_ps(x_lo, x_hi, 0b10101010);
    __m256 y = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(x_b, _mm256_set_epi32(7,5,3,1,6,4,2,0));
    return y;
}

__m256 stide_2_load_even(float * a){
    __m256 x_lo = _mm256_loadu_ps(&a[0]);
    __m256 x_hi = _mm256_loadu_ps(&a[7]);
    __m256 x_b = _mm256_blend_ps(x_lo, x_hi, 0b10101010);
    __m256 y = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(x_b, _mm256_set_epi32(7,5,3,1,6,4,2,0));
    return y;
}


int main()
{
    float a[] = {0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1, 9.1, 10.1, 11.1, 12.1, 13.1, 14.1, 15.1};
    float b[8];
    __m256 y = stide_2_load_odd(a);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(b, y);
    printf("odd indices 1, 3, 5, ...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("y[%i] = %f \n", i, b[i]);
    }
    y = stide_2_load_even(a);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(b, y);
    printf("\neven indices 0, 2, 4, ...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("y[%i] = %f \n", i, b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$gcc -Wall -O3 -march=skylake -o main *.c


$main
odd indices 1, 3, 5, ...
y[0] = 1.100000 
y[1] = 3.100000 
y[2] = 5.100000 
y[3] = 7.100000 
y[4] = 9.100000 
y[5] = 11.100000 
y[6] = 13.100000 
y[7] = 15.100000 

even indices 0, 2, 4, ...
y[0] = 0.100000 
y[1] = 2.100000 
y[2] = 4.100000 
y[3] = 6.100000 
y[4] = 8.100000 
y[5] = 10.100000 
y[6] = 12.100000 
y[7] = 14.100000
```

Here unaligned loads are used. On modern cpu’s these do not cause any performance penalty, as long as the read operation from memory does not cross any cache line boundary. Therefore it is preferable to call these two functions with a 64 byte aligned address `a`. See also Peter Cordes’ [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848871/fastest-stride-2-gather/62859064?noredirect=1#comment111160835_62859064).

Comment: Note that `vblendps`+`vpermps` will almost certainly be faster than `vgatherdps`, see [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848871/fastest-stride-2-gather#comment111142556_62848871)' comment.

Comment: `vshufps` allows both loads to be aligned.  But if you know where you are relative to 64-byte alignment, you can avoid cache-line splits by having the `_mm256_loadu_ps(&a[1]);` be with `a` at the start of a cache line instead of overlapping into the next one.  Then it's still full performance on Intel.

Comment: You want a *64-byte* aligned `a`.  If it's 32 but *not* 64, your first load will cache-split.